# Lombok: @RequiredArgsConstructor creates constructor from final but not from @NotNull

Tags: java, constructor, lombok, intellij-lombok-plugin

I am attempting to create a basic Recipe class with `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, but Lombok doesn't appear to be creating the required args constructor correctly. While it will successfully create other constructors, such as `@AllArgsConstructor`, the required args constructor is empty even when I have values annotated with `@NotEmpty`/`@NotNull`. I have double-checked that I've imported `RequiredArgsConstructor`.

Here is a stripped-down version of my class:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Recipe
{
    @NotEmpty
    String name;

    @NotNull
    ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients;

    @NotNull
    ArrayList<String> steps;

    // Time in mins
    int time;

    String creator;
}
```

The constructor created by Lombok, which I checked in my built class file, is empty.

Note that when I make the `@NotNull` fields final in my class, Lombok will create the proper required args constructor:

```
public Recipe(String name, ArrayList<Ingredient> ingredients, ArrayList<String> steps) {
        this.name = name;
        this.ingredients = ingredients;
        this.steps = steps;
    }
```

So it appears as if it's ignoring the `@NotNull` annotations. I would appreciate any guidance on what I might be doing wrong here. Thank you!

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong, that is how lombok works. Required arguments are arguments that cannot be set **after** the object has been constructed, hence `final` fields. The `@NotNull` doesn't say anything about **when** the reference needs to be set (could be a setter before persisting it).

Comment: @M.Deinum On the Project Lombok site, it says "All non-initialized final fields get a parameter, as well as any fields that are marked as NonNull that aren't initialized where they are declared. " Would this not mean that my NotNull-marked items should be part of the generated constructor?

Comment: `lombok.NonNull` isn't `javax.validation.constraints,NotNull`. It is a totally different annotation, even a specialized lombok one.

Comment: `lombok.NonNull` is the only annotation really making Lombok forcing non-null. All other "No[tn][Nn]ulll" annotations can mean anything, e.g., that the field may be null, but then the validation fails. Therefore it's not required to set the field immediately in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I incorrectly interpreted the Project Lombok documentation, which says that "All non-initialized final fields get a parameter, as well as any fields that are marked as `@NonNull` that aren't initialized where they are declared."

I took `@NonNull` to mean any field that was marked with `@NotNull` or equivalent, from `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull/NotEmpty`, when in fact it literally meant `@NonNull` from `lombok.NonNull`.